# My admin.TabularInline class returns exception: object has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

So I've been Googling around and can't find a solution to my problem. I'm honestly quite puzzled, so thanks for taking a look.

**mysite/mysite/urls.py:**

```
...
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                         url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
...
```

**mysite/upgradelists/admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from upgrademe.models import GPU, CPU

class CPUAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CPU

admin.site.register(CPU, CPUAdmin)
```

**returned error:**

```
AttributeError at /admin/
'CPUAdmin' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

However, if I change admin.py to:

```
class CPUAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = CPU
```

Then all is well. (although, irrelevant note: I believe the 'model = CPU' portion is redundant?)

Any help/insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Google has left me stumped, and searches over StackOverflow have turned up nothing that I can see is related.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, Google led me to this thread and it didn't help. I solved it while I was about to post my question.

I don't even know if it's the same problem you had, but here it is:

```
class UserAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserAnswer
class UserQuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserAnswerInline]
admin.site.register(UserQuestion, UserAnswerInline)
```

The correct code:

```
class UserAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserAnswer
class UserQuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserAnswerInline]
admin.site.register(UserQuestion, UserQuestionAdmin)
```

Spot the difference? Yup, wrong class name. Took me 5 hours before I decided to create a new question here, then figured it out while explaining the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem like this.

You can try this to fix this problem:

```
class CPUInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CPU

class CPUAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CPUInline]

admin.site.register(CPU, CPUAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't register a tabular admin class directly with the admin site. TabularAdmin is a subclass of InlineAdmin, and as such is only for use in the `inlines` attribute of a full ModelAdmin.

Comment: Staff user are not able to see this inline, then when I go to add permission then I didn't found the permission for that model to add. So what's the hack now?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens to be coming from the part you expect least.

You can’t register InlineModelAdmin or it’s subclasses in the admin site. You can only use them in  attributes of ModelAdmin classes.

This is the the most common cause of such error and it’s quite difficult to spot

Comment: Please add a code snippet while answering. If you wish to provide a suggestion, you should write it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all correct in their own ways.  Essentially, the offending line is `admin.site.register(CPU, CPUAdmin)`.

Because this Model is included inline in another Model (which I'm assuming is `GPU` because it's the only other Model you are importing), you shouldn't register it but only the Model in which it will be inline-ed.  So, removing the register line from admin.py will fix the `object has no attribute 'urls'`.

Answer (score 0):

An inline can only be used in a modelAdmin that is why you get that error. As per my understanding on your code you need to write your code as.

```
class CPUInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CPU
@admin.register(CPU)
class CPUAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CPUInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

###### models.py

```
from django.db import models



class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('First name',max_length=100)
    students = models.ForeignKey('Student',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('First name',max_length=100)
```

###### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Teacher, Student
from .models import Teacher as Teach


class TeacherInline(admin.TabularInline):      
    model = Teacher

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name')
    inlines = [TeacherInline]


admin.site.register(Student,StudentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Teach)
```

[image]

But this does not show `list_display` and other options. For doing that, use flowing code:

###### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Teacher, Student
from .models import Teacher as Teach

class TeacherInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Teacher

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name')
    inlines = [TeacherInline]

class TeachAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name')

admin.site.register(Student,StudentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Teach,TeachAdmin)
```